# htaccess redirect in Yii

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, yii, http-status-code-404

I am using Yii framework, and I have a problem with redirect. I want to redirect from a old url which apears in google search to my homepage. But the redirect does not get effected and I get the 404 error. Can I specify somehow that .htm extentions wouldn't get 404 error and instead redirect to the homepage?

Here is the redirect in my htaccess file:

```
Redirect /file\s_mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano.htm http://marionettecolla.org/
```

the old url is this:

```
http://www.marionettecolla.org/file%20_mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano.htm
```

and I want to redirect it to the home page:

```
http://www.marionettecolla.org/
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the old url which apears in google search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Redirect /file%20_mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano.htm http://www.marionettecolla.org/
```

If you want to use regular expression try this :

```
RedirectMatch /file[ ]_mostra_milano/mostra_marionette-milano\.htm$ http://www.marionettecolla.org/
```

Last but not least, here is an online [.htaccess generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php) for creating or updating your .htaccess.